# extreme teeth and stomach pain with work in a few hours

Tags: health, time-off

I had an appointment for my braces today and I am now having extreme teeth pain (I have a new wire and chain bands, very painful). I took medicine and it has been a few hours since so they should have started working but didn't. My stomach is also hurting but that could be due to anxiety. I'm not sure if i should ask for today off since I'm extremely new to my job (this would be my third day) and I have work in about an hour. I work at a thrift store and it hasn't been busy so it wouldn't be short staffed or anything if I didn't go but I don't want to risk losing the job because of this.

edit: I'm sorry for wasting time, I didn't know where else to go for this and I'm panicking because my father said I could get fired over this.

Comment: Phone in sick as per the contract

Comment: This is not the forum for acute health problems. You're wasting precious time.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to sound harsh. To clarify, you are wasting your time by consulting this forum with an hour to ago instead of a nurse or clinic. I hope it is working out well in real time.

Answer (score 6):

If you are in pain, you go see a doctor.

Let your employer know that you go see a doctor for an unplanned emergency as soon as you can, so they can handle it accordingly.

Once your doctor has treated you and made a recommendation on what to do, let your employer know.

Look into your contract or employee guidelines what to do in case of sickness, whom to inform and when.

In any civilized country, your employer is not allowed to fire you for this.

Comment: And yet, at-will employment

Comment: Well, I do not consider US at-will states in any way "civilized" concerning labor laws. They basically have none. But the OP did not specify that they were in such a state or even in the US.

Comment: @bwmat Name one civilized country with at-will employment.

Comment: The United States of America